# how can i center the text in bootstrap. img should be in its fixed position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center the text I have tried many ways but i can't.if any one could help me find out the solution....

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



 <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex ml-5">
                <img src="rec.svg" height="50" class="mt-2">
                <p style="font-size:30px;" class="text-muted text-center ml-3">Bgfjfk</p>   
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You want to centre the text, but you've also placed it beside an image. So what does centre the text mean? Centre the whole thing, including the image? Centre the text as if the image wasn't there? Centre the text in the space remaining after accounting for the image? Something else?

Comment: only the text should be center img will be in fixed position

Comment: You need to put the text in a block level element and then centre it. I'd advise learning HTML and CSS first before trying to make things with rapid prototyping frameworks.

Comment: @DCdaz — It is centred in a block level element. That element is just too narrow for that to be noticed.

Comment: I wrote an article a few years ago on centering anything in CSS & HTML
https://love2dev.com/blog/absolute-centering-css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap utility class `justify-content-center` on your `col-12` element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50" class="mt-2">
    <p style="font-size:30px;" class="text-muted text-center ml-3">Bgfjfk</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50" class="mt-2 position-absolute" style="left: 15px">
    <p style="font-size:30px;" class="text-muted text-center ml-3">Bgfjfk</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i don't want image to move the image should be fixed only the text to be center

Comment: @Aisha *without changing the HTML structure*, you can use `position-absolute` on the `img` with an inline style (this could be moved to your CSS file) to add padding. Updated answer with both approaches

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row mt-3">
   <div class="col-12 ml-5">
      <p style="font-size:30px;text-align:center " class="text-muted ml-3"> 
         <img src="AutoUnder/rec.svg" height="42" class="mt-2" style="vertical-align:middle">
         Bgfjfk
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey i want the img to in it fixed position only the text should be center